# Mysql sum of the different column if the same value

Tags: mysql

I need to get sum number of same value in column ex

```
 Full texts     ID  name    1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8   
            1  sai on mane  Yellow  Purple  Yellow  Purple   Red    Orange
```

i would like to get sum of yellow=2, sum of purple=2, sum of Red=1, sum of Orange=1;
etc...
Please help thank a lot

Comment: What language you're using, you can get all values using mysql then check it using if else statement with your language.

Comment: If you're storing all those colours in columns of one row then this will be quite awkward with SQL. You should change your DB design.

Answer (score 2):

You have a very denormalized table structure. You should really be storing this data in rows, *a la*:

```
ID num color
1  1   Yellow
1  2   Purple
1  3   Yellow
1  4   Purple
1  5   Red
1  6   Orange
```

---

But, assuming you're forced to work with this...first I would flatten your table:

```
select `1` as color from myTable
union all 
select `2` as color from myTable
union all 
select `3` as color from myTable
union all 
select `4` as color from myTable
union all 
select `5` as color from myTable
union all 
select `6` as color from myTable
union all 
select `7` as color from myTable
union all 
select `8` as color from myTable
```

Then you can easily aggregate from this query:

```
select color, count(1)
from (
    select `1` as color from myTable
    union all 
    select `2` as color from myTable
    union all 
    select `3` as color from myTable
    union all 
    select `4` as color from myTable
    union all 
    select `5` as color from myTable
    union all 
    select `6` as color from myTable
    union all 
    select `7` as color from myTable
    union all 
    select `8` as color from myTable
) x
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this,

```
select colorName, count(colorName) from tableName group by colorName;
```

Comment: This would be my guess, but I think the OP needs to change his DB design to do this.